# How to check status of SnsAlarm in AWS DataPipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, amazon-data-pipeline

I have configured a data pipeline which executes a SQL statement and dumps data into a S3 bucket. Everything in the pipeline is working fine. The data is being dumped successfully. Today I added an SNSAlarm to the OnSuccess event on my Activity and subscribed a SQS queue to that SNS topic. However, I do not get any message in the queue even though the Activity succeeds and neither do I see any sort of log related to SNS success or failure.

Has anyone used SnsAlarm in AWS Datapipeline before? Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can attach snsAlarms (they are an action of a datapipeline) to Activities as well as the pipeline itself.

```
{
  "id" : "SuccessNotify",
  "name" : "SuccessNotify",
  "type" : "SnsAlarm",
  "topicArn" : "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:28619EXAMPLE:ExampleTopic",
  "subject" : "COPY SUCCESS: #{node.@scheduledStartTime}",
  "message" : "Files were copied from #{node.input} to #{node.output}."
}
```

Be sure to update `topicArn` with the Arn of the SNS topic you wish to receive alerts at. 
More Info: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-snsalarm.html

More Info on Datapipeline Objects: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-pipeline-objects.html

Comment: Actually, I figured out the problem myself. It wasn't working because I hadn't given right permissions to my SNS Topic and SQS Queue. However, I am still going to accept your answer because it does answer my original question to some level.